# Get array keys when in argument in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, key

I'm passing some arrays as arguments inside a function. For example:

```
test($someArray[2][3]);
```

In that case the function gets the value stored in (2,3) but there is a way to get the keys value (2,3) from inside the function to work with? The function should use the x,y position of the value to do some calculations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not this way, no. If you call `test($someArray[2][3])`, then PHP will only pass the value, but not any reference where this value comes from. Its cleaner to pass the values separately anyway

```
function test($x, $y, $value) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the simplest way. Thought there was some dark function to do the job but well, I'll have to do it "properly". Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the subscript will be performed *before* the function receives it.

So if your code is...

```
$someArray = array(
   2 => array(3 => 'Hello');
);

function test($arg) {

}

test($someArray[2][3]);
```

Then `$arg` will be a string `Hello`. It doesn't know or care about where it came from.

Comment: no, the `$arg` would be `NULL` and raise a notice since the array you created is named `$arr`, not `$someArray`.. :P

Answer (score 0):

You're only passing the single element at `[2][3]`; once inside the function, there is no array. If you need the positions, you should pass the array/element and the indices separately:

```
test($someArray, 2, 3); // if you might access other elements too
```

or:

```
test($someArray[2][3], 2, 3); // if you don't need other elements
```